# Unconventional use of Iterator to iterate over a collection

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, while-loop, iterator

I am aware of the conventional iterator creation-usage for a `List<String> list` as below:

```
//Conventional-style
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator()
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   String string = iterator.next();
   //...further code goes here
}
```

However, in the accepted answer of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing), I came across this unusual `for` loop usage with `Iterator`:

```
//Unconventional for loop style
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
    //...further code goes here
}
```

Now, I'd like to know:

1. Does this unconventional style create the iterator on the collection for each iteration over and over again? Or is it somehow a special kind of intelligent for-loop, which creates the iterator once and reuses it?
   If it creates an iterator each time, shouldn't it be a performance concern?
2. Can we replace the while loop line in the conventional style with
   `for(;iterator.hasNext();)`, if I were to use a `for` loop only?

PS: I am well aware of the enhanced for loop use on a collection. I am looking at this with the intention of 'safe' removal of elements, without causing a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: That is quite a convential use of an iterator; and it creates the iterator only once (the first statement of a for loop, if any, is only ever executed once). In fact it is exactly equivalent to your first piece of code

Comment: Not exactly equivalent, this way the `iterator` variable can't be used outside the `for` loop anymore, which is quite handy.

Comment: Your first question is very strange (at least to me). Would ask the same if you see this `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`? Would you also ask if `i` is recreated on each iteration? (And yes, this is the exact same type of a `for` loop)

Comment: @Tom: Yea.. It seems pretty silly now that I realized it. Thanks for pointing it out with such a simple straightforward example. I clearly missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiom you call "unconventional" is actually the recommended one because it restricts the scope of the iterator variable to the loop where it is used.

1. The iterator is created once, before the loop begins. This follows from the general semantics of the `for` loop, which I warmly advise you get acquainted with.
2. You can, but you would not be recommended to. Such an idiom would be a pointless obfuscation of the `while` idiom.

Finally, note that for 99% of use cases all of the above is moot because you really should be using either the *enhanced for* loop or Java 8 `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Marko.. The 'restricting the scope' part is new learning to me. I clearly missed the 'general semantics' of the for loop. Thanks for putting such a warm answer to my silly question.

Comment: But the ´for(Iterator<T> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) { doSomething(i.next()); }´ was the best way to iterate over a collection prior to introducing Iterable<T>. And still is if you want to use the i.remove() operation.

Comment: @jan `Iterable` on its own has nothing to do with it (but I guess you mean its connection with the _enhanced for_ loop). Yes, before Java 5 this was our best idiom and yes, there is that 1% of cases where you need to call anything else but `hasNext()` and `next()`.

Comment: Ok because as the answer to the 2nd question you told OP that it is a pointless obfuscation of the while idiom.

Comment: @jan That's right, it most definitely is. Maybe you have misunderstood which idiom my statement pertains to, though.

Comment: Your statement pertains to the forEach idiom. I can see that, but it has the downside, that you cannot modify the collection while iterating over it.

So as the OP is "looking at this with the intention of 'safe' removal of element" you should have probably pointed out that if she wants to remove an element safely, he/she should use the for(... hasNext()...) way. As this is the preferred one if you want to do that.

Comment: No, my statement was that `for (;it.hasNext();) {...}` was a pointless obfuscation.

Answer (score 2):

Java is derived from C, and thus `for (A; B; C) { P; }` has the same semantics as `A; while (B) { P; C; }`. The only difference is the scope of the variables. In particular, the `A` part is only executed once. So your two code examples do exactly the same, but in the `for`-variant the scope of the variable is restricted.

The more modern way of iterating through a collection is the enhance for loop:

```
for (String string : list) {
    ...
}
```

However, if you want to delete or change items while iterating through it, you still need the iterator version. For example:

```
for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String string = it.next();
    if (someFunction(string)) {
        it.delete();
    }
}
```

has no enhanced for-loop equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
No, it does not create an iterator over and over again.. This was the perfectly fine style before Java included the interface **`Iterable<T>`**.
If you want to remove an item while iterating over the collection you have to use the **`iterator.remove()`** method if it is provided.. Because otherwise a ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown.

If you do not want to remove an Item while iterating over the collection then you should just use the for each concept, which is provided by every collection that implements the **`Iterable<T>`** interface. (link in the end for more information)

```
for (String s : yourList) {
  ... // do something with the string
}
```

**2.**
Yes!! Use the for loop idiom. But as I said, if you **do not** want to use the **`iterator.remove()`** operation, but just want to iterate over the collection, you should use the provided for each concept.

You can find a lot of information on the downsides of the **`iterator.next()`** approach here and why the newly integrated for:each concept is better:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html